# Completely stumped on proving parallel lines question. A hint?

Tags: vectors

Ok, sorry for not being able to show much work but this question just confuses me and it's also got a time limit attached, so I apologize for that.

the question:
[image]
Consider six points Q1,R1,Q2,R2,Q3,R3 that lie alternately on two distinct lines intersecting a the point P. If the vector −−−→Q1R2 is parallel to the vector --−→Q2R3 and the vector −−−→Q2R1 is parallel to the vector −−−→Q3R2, then show that the vector −−−→Q1R1 is parallel to the vector −−−→Q3R3.

All I can think of for a possible solution is to prove that vector Q1R3, the one that bisects parallelogram R2R3Q2Q1, also bisects parallelogram R1R3Q1Q3.

I'll be working in the meantime, but if anyone could drop a hint as to how I could possibly work towards, that'd be great.

[image: q1r1]

Comment: Oh and please ask if there's any details missing, if you'd like a picture...

Comment: Oh and I just realized there aren't any parallelograms in the whole diagram...ah...

Comment: We need to know where these points are. Your diagram does not show this.

Comment: So prove R1Q1 and R3Q3 is parallel

Comment: Now that I think about it maybe it has more to do with angles.

Comment: I could not figure this one out... it seems obviously true, but I'm forgetting some basic geometry rules.

Answer (score 0):

[image: qrparallel]

$\Delta q_1 x q_2, \Delta q_1 r_2 q_3$ and $\Delta q_2 y q_3$ are similar.

So are $\Delta r_1 x r_2, \Delta r_1 q_2 r_3$ and $\Delta r_2 y r_3$.

Effectively this means that $\Delta q_3 y r_3\equiv \Delta q_1 x r_1$.